# Redis memory optimization for hashmap vs String keys

Tags: java, data-structures, redis, memory-optimization

I have been trying to evaluate the memory size of the redis in two scenario.

Scenario-1:

```
    String commonString = "Test";
    long commonId = 1234567890L;
    int size = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        jedis.set((commonString+"_"+commonId+"_KEY_"+i).getBytes(),("Value_"+i).getBytes());
        DebugParams debugParams = DebugParams.OBJECT(commonString+"_"+commonId+"_KEY_"+i);
        size += Integer.parseInt(debugged.split(":")[4].split(" ")[0]);
    }
```

In this scenario, the size is 892 bytes

Scenario-2:

```
    String commonString = "Test";
    long commonId = 1234567890L;
    int size = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        jedis.hset((commonString+"_"+commonId).getBytes(),SafeEncoder.encode("KEY_"+i),("Value_"+i).getBytes());
    }
    DebugParams debugParams = DebugParams.OBJECT(commonString+"_"+commonId);
    String debugged = jedis.debug(debugParams);
    size = Integer.parseInt(debugged.split(":")[4].split(" ")[0]);
```

In this scenario, it takes 925 bytes.

> Since Redis 2.2 many data types are optimized to use less space up to a certain size. Hashes, Lists, Sets composed of just integers, and Sorted Sets, when smaller than a given number of elements, and up to a maximum element size, are encoded in a very memory efficient way that uses up to 10 times less memory (with 5 time less memory used being the average saving).

I have tried for this optimization, but i haven't achieved it. The configuration is default configuration. What might have gone wrong?

## Edited

**Scenario-1**

```
    String commonString = "Test";
    long commonId = 1234567890L;
    jedis.flushAll();
    String info1 = jedis.info();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 75; i++)
    {
        jedis.set(commonString+"_"+commonId+"_KEY_"+i, "VALUE_"+i);
    }
    String info2 = jedis.info();
```

In Scenario-1, used memory in info1 is "used_memory:844640" and used memory in info2 is "used_memory:852176". So, the difference between the info2 and info1 is 7536 bytes.

**Scenario-2**

```
    String commonString = "Test";
    long commonId = 1234567890L;
    jedis.flushAll();
    String info1 = jedis.info();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 75; i++)
    {
        jedis.hset(commonString+"_"+commonId,"KEY_"+i,"VALUE_"+i);
    }
    String info2 = jedis.info();
```

In Scenario-2, used memory in info1 is "used_memory:845576" and used memory in info2 is "used_memory:847208". So, the difference between the info2 and info1 is 1632 bytes.

Have I evaluated correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the documentation about [`DEBUG OBJECT`](https://redis.io/commands/debug-object), you'll learn that:

> DEBUG OBJECT is a debugging command that should not be used by clients. Check the OBJECT command instead.

Put a little differently, whatever you're getting back from `DebugParams.OBJECT` is in most likelihood almost if not entirely irrelevant to what you are trying to achieve.

The good news are that Redis v4 introduces the new `MEMORY` (Doctor) command. The following is an excerpt from [@antirez's 'The first release candidate of Redis 4.0 is out'](http://antirez.com/news/110):

> ## 6. The new MEMORY command.
>
> I love it, as much as I loved LATENCY DOCTOR that once introduced cut the percentage of “My Redis is slow” complains in the mailing list
>   to a minor fraction. Now we have it for the memory issues as well.
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY DOCTOR
> Hi Sam, this instance is empty or is using very little memory, my issues detector can't be used in these conditions. Please, leave for
> ```
>
> your mission on Earth and fill it with some data. The new Sam and I
>   will be back to our programming as soon as I finished rebooting.
>
> Movie rights owners will probably sue me for taking inspirations of sci-fi dialogues but that’s fine. Bring oranges for me when I’ll be
>   in jail.
>
> MEMORY does a lot more than that.
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY HELP
> 1) "MEMORY USAGE <key> [SAMPLES <count>] - Estimate memory usage of key"
> 2) "MEMORY STATS                         - Show memory usage details"
> 3) "MEMORY PURGE                         - Ask the allocator to release memory"
> 4) "MEMORY MALLOC-STATS                  - Show allocator internal stats"
> ```
>
> The memory usage reporting of the USAGE subcommand is going to be very useful, but also the in depth informations provided by “STATS”.
>
> For now all this is totally not documented, so have fun figuring out what the heck it does.

Comment: I'm using redis-3.2.8. How can I find out the exact memory taken in scenario-1 and scenario-2?

Comment: 1) Reset Redis 2) take baseline from `INFO memory` 3) create a significant amount of identical keys 4) take another reading 5) repeat for each experiment and compare. Inaccurate, but the best you can do before v4.